Preload database tables and its join tables when we are using Hibernate GenerationType.IDENTITY
I'm using Quarkus with Panache and Hibernate 6, and SQL Server. Our entities are using GenerationType.IDENTITY.
We need to preload the database before to start the application. At dev we are using a simple import.sql file with insert statements, but I believe this problem is going to be the same at production where we are going to use Flyway.
Our problem is that we are getting an exception as soon as we start our tests.

2024-07-30 08:15:50,608 WARN  [org.hib.rea.pro.ser.ReactiveGenerationTarget] (vert.x-eventloop-thread-0) HR000021: DDL command failed [org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException: error executing SQL statement [{number=544, state=1, severity=16, message='Cannot insert explicit value for identity column in table 'BUSINESS_UNITS' when IDENTITY_INSERT is set to OFF.', serverName='6de5913051ec', lineNumber=1}] [INSERT INTO BUSINESS_UNITS(id, code, name, desc) VALUES (1, 'it-po', 'IT', 'Information Technology PO')]]
[

Certainly this error is because we are adding the id in the insert statement. But how could we know the generated id in order to also do the inserts on the join tables?

Following the suggestion of AlwaysLearning I tried to use SET IDENTITY_INSERT
[Hibernate]

SET
    IDENTITY_INSERT BUSINESS_UNITS
        ON
[Hibernate]
    INSERT
    INTO
        BUSINESS_UNITS
        (id, code, name, desc)
    VALUES
        (1, 'it-po', 'IT', 'Information Technology PO')


2024-07-30 09:12:52,121 WARN  [org.hib.eng.jdb.spi.SqlExceptionHelper] (vert.x-eventloop-thread-6) SQL Error: 544, SQLState: S0001
2024-07-30 09:12:52,122 ERROR [org.hib.eng.jdb.spi.SqlExceptionHelper] (vert.x-eventloop-thread-6) {number=544, state=1, severity=16, message='Cannot insert explicit value for identity column in table 'BUSINESS_UNITS' when IDENTITY_INSERT is set to OFF.', serverName='427ad53af72d', lineNumber=1}
2024-07-30 09:12:52,128 WARN  [org.hib.rea.pro.ser.ReactiveGenerationTarget] (vert.x-eventloop-thread-6) HR000021: DDL command failed [org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException: error executing SQL statement [{number=544, state=1, severity=16, message='Cannot insert explicit value for identity column in table 'BUSINESS_UNITS' when IDENTITY_INSERT is set to OFF.', serverName='427ad53af72d', lineNumber=1}] [INSERT INTO BUSINESS_UNITS(id, code, name, desc) VALUES (1, 'it-po', 'IT', 'Information Technology PO')]]
[


Have you considered using Flyway to apply data in addition to schema changes? Really, its schema change scripts should only be considered a starting point since on SQL Server they often need changes to apply things like the full set of index options.

Whether you use Flyway or Hibernate you'll still need to be aware of SET IDENTITY_INSERT for tables with database generated identity values.

@AlwayLearning, We are considering to use Flyway. But we are still investigating the way we are going to do that.

@AlwaysLeaning, I will update the question about my trial using the SET_IDENTITY_INSERT, that seems not being considered.

Your Hibernate logging looks like it's submitting SET IDENTITY_INSERT in a separate batch, it needs to be applied in the same session as the insert. e.g.: db<>fiddle

Also, don't forget to SET IDENTITY_INSERT yourtable OFF when you're done with it, ideally in some sort of try/catch

@AlwaysLearning, seems that somehow hibernate (or panache) is not doing the right thing...

@siggemannen, thanks. we already have them.
